# Checkbox onchange function is always undefined in React component class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My onchange function on my checkbox is always undefined.  I made a sandbox to simplify my issue.  I've tried changing it back and forth between an arrow and a regular function, and leaving the binding as its default state vs tying it to its binding in the constructor.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.renderCheckboxes = this.renderCheckboxes.bind(this);
    this.checkboxChange = this.checkboxChange.bind(this);
  }

  checkboxChange = (event) => {
    console.log("CHANGED");
  }

  renderCheckboxes(checkboxes) {
    return checkboxes.map(function (obj, idx) {
      return (
        <div>
          <label>{obj.name}</label>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.checkboxChange} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    const cbList = [
      { name: "A", mood: "Happy" },
      { name: "B", mood: "Sad" },
      { name: "C", mood: "Mad" }
    ];

    return <>{this.renderCheckboxes(cbList)}</>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

[My Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-yonath-4g4im?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is undefined because you are losing your context when your `checkboxes.map` happens.

```
  renderCheckboxes(checkboxes) {
    return checkboxes.map(function (obj, idx) { // here
      return (
        <div>
          <label>{obj.name}</label>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.checkboxChange} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
```

You can change the function for an arrow function, so you won't lose context:

```
  renderCheckboxes(checkboxes) {
    return checkboxes.map((obj, idx) => { // here
      return (
        <div>
          <label>{obj.name}</label>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.checkboxChange} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
```

It might not be the case, but if you need to send some parameter on your `checkboxChange` call, you could use it like this:

```
  checkboxChange = (value) => { // need to set the variable here
    console.log(value);
  }

  renderCheckboxes(checkboxes) {
    return checkboxes.map((obj, idx) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <label>{obj.name}</label>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={() => this.checkboxChange('test')} />  <!-- so you can pass it from here -->
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix, it's because the binding doesn't work within the `map` function like you have now. To see this in action, try just rendering one checkbox, without `map` and you'll see your checkbox change method work.

Two changes I suggest:

1. Change map method to an arrow function:

```
return checkboxes.map((obj, idx) => {
    ...
}
```

2. Change onChange to an arrow function:

```
onChange={() => this.checkboxChange()}
```